# v.out.ogr -c flag in GRASS GIS is filling islands

Tags: grass-gis, vector, features, geometries

I have a very big shapefile (polygons) to load in GRASS GIS, thus I am selecting only relevant rows based on a .txt file with some conditions (e.g., the ID of the polygon). However, when I try to save my relevant polygons, for some of them I receive a warning message, such as this one:

> WARNING: 160 features without category were skipped. Features without category are written only when -c flag is given.

I then tried to use the `-c` flag when saving the polygons through `v.out.ogr` (`-c` flag export features without category - not labeled -, otherwise only features with category are exported). Using the `-c` flags "fills" parts of the map that should not be filled (e.g., lakes): indeed, I receive another warning message:

> The map contains islands. With the -c flag, islands will appear as filled areas, not holes in the output map.

I guess having big parts of the map filled when they shouldn't be (such as Caspian Sea) may mess up my analyses, thus I am trying to understand what and which are the features without category and if there is a way to both preserve the features without category **and** not have filled areas.

Is it possible, is it advised, do you have any suggestions?

I am running GRASS GIS 7.8.6

Comment: Some clarifications:
Is your question about loading a shapefile **into** GRASS, or saving a GRASS vector **out** to a shapefile??

You speak about islands, so I assume this is a polygon vector??

What was wrong with the output that you got without the `-c` flag??

Comment: I think you are asking multiple questions on a similar theme. Some marked and some not which makes it hard for a single focused question to be recognized and answered.

Comment: @Micha I wanted to load only the relevant rows of the .shp and then export them with v.in.ogr; yes, it is a polygon vector. The output of the -c flag has "filled" parts, parts that should not be filled (such as lakes). I don't know why it calls it "islands".

Comment: (I updated the question, hope it's clearer now, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GRASS GIS the concept of "island" refers to any area that is within another area, and does not touch any of the boundaries. Typically, as the warning message points out, these islands are holes in the outer area. For example a lake inside a larger region. The category value of area vectors is always attached to the area **centroid**. All real areas (not islands) will be get a centroid, and so also a category value, when you import from a shapefile (assuming the import and clean operation complete successfully). On the contrary the islands do not get a centroid and so no category. Then when you go to export back to a shapefile, you get the warning that there are areas (islands) without a category, and they will not be exported. Usually this is what is expected.

Without seeing your data, or at least the output from `v.info`, it's hard to say for sure, but I would think that exporting **without the `-c`** flag should give you a correct output shapefile.

Adding further details, such as the exact commands that you used, will allow us to give a more focused answer.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: Thanks Micha, it is clear. This is the output of `v.info` on the file created **without** the `-c` flag.

`Map format: native; Type of map: vector (level: 2); Number of points: 0 Number of centroids: 221; Number of lines: 0; Number of boundaries: 564;Number of areas: 381; Number of islands: 181; Map is 3D: No; Number of dblinks: 1; Projection: Latitude-Longitude; N:  83:37:38.768131N; S: 31:55:00.248131N; E: 179:57:40.68E; W: 179:57:30.6W; Digitization threshold: 0.`

Comment: And this is the output of `v.info` on the file created **with** the `-c` flag. `Map format: native; Type of map: vector (level: 2); Number of points: 0 Number of centroids: 381; Number of lines: 0; Number of boundaries: 564;Number of areas: 381; Number of islands: 181; Map is 3D: No; Number of dblinks: 1; Projection: Latitude-Longitude; N: 83:37:38.768131N; S: 31:55:00.248131N; E: 179:57:40.68E; W: 179:57:30.6W; Digitization threshold: 0.`

Comment: Indeed, as you were saying, the file created with the `-c` flag contains more centroids. Now it's clear and I also think that **not** using the flag will be okay. As for the commands used, I just created a `while read` and `do` loop (if this is the correct name of this) where I used `v.in.ogr` to load the .shp (with `where` to set the condition based on the id columns of a .txt file), `g.region`, and `v.out.ogr` with (or without) the `-c` flag.